# Google App Engine with Firebase - can't add dependencies

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to connect a backend module in Android Studio to Firebase using the tutorial here - https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio#adding_dependencies_to_the_backend_module

I cannot add the dependencies for some reason. I can't find them on the list. If I try to add them manually, I get a Gradle sync error.

For the main app module, Firebase is connected and it's functioning correctly. I set this up using Android Studio's build in Firebase tool. I've tried using this tool again but it's made no difference.

Here's my build.gradle for the backend:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.42'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
}
```

Here's the error I get if I add the dependencies manually, as shown in the code above:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op7kx.png)

Comment: Please show exactly what you are trying to do in your gradle file and any exact error messages you're seeing.

Comment: @DougStevenson please see my edit, added the gradle file and the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting errors on these dependencies.  They don't have versions specified:

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
```

Every maven dependency requires a group id, artifact id, and a version string.

Also, the "firebase-server-sdk" dependency doesn't make sense to me.  Access to firebase backend services is now done through the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

My guess is that the tutorial you linked to is simply very much out of date, and you can no longer follow it exactly, but maybe you can still learn something from it otherwise.

Comment: Adding the dependency in the tutorial you linked doesn't through up any errors. The three dependencies I'm trying to add - are they needed? Or shall I replace them with something else if this part of the tutorial is out of date?

Comment: You'll have to make a judgement call on your own.  I haven't gone through that tutorial myself.

Comment: Thanks! I think I've got it working. I have another question if you could help with this? Is it correct that I can use Google App Engine to run scheduled jobs? I.e, every day, make an update to the Firebase database (based on results from another RESTful API service)?

Comment: If you don't mind, could you ask that as a separate question so it's easy for others to search and discover?

Comment: Have done - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47557941/scheduled-updates-on-firebase-database-using-google-app-engine